# How to set fixed width in p-card

Tags: angular, primeng

I have following html

```
<p-card class="p-d-md-none p-d-xl-flex p-flex-row card">
  <div class="p-d-none p-d-lg-flex p-flex-row p-ai-center p-jc-center">
  .....
  </div>
 </p-card>
```

I want to set fixed width to p-card so it won`t change width when I change screen size from xl to md

How can I do that?

Comment: Remove the attributes.
`p-d-xl-flex, p-d-lg-flex` and then give some width that you want.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi but now it has space from left side when i change size of screen

Comment: can you try to create a little stackblitz to know more about it.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi Already fixed by yourself

Comment: Glad to help  you.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi You should consider posting this as an answer and get it accepting  so others can see that your problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the attributes `p-d-xl-flex, p-d-lg-flex` and then to give an width.